# how do i get a picture to have a height of 100%

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap templates and have split the page into a fixed sidebar and the remaining part of the page is one big picture. However the picture will not match the height of the sidebar. There is always a white gap after the picture even though the sidebar has 100% height. So how can i make my picture take up 100% height?

My html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
  <div class="sidebar affix">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 pic">
    <div><img src ="homepage/pic5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Css:

```
.row.content {
    height: 684px;
}

.sidenav {
 height: 100%;
}

.pic .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
}

.pic {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar  {
    width: 22.5%;
    top: 0px;
}

.pic > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this

```
.pic > .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing your `img` in an `div` which you give position absolute, while you give the `img` position relative in the `div` with position absolute.

```
position: absolute
```

Places an element absolute, meaning on its self. There for any heights or width of any elements around it will not effect the element, it is absolute.

I havent tested it but you should remove the `position:absolute`, `position:relative` and the div around your `img`.